# C# Option parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

When I use the following code for a method I get a red squiggly line at the very end, with a message `invalid expression term ')'`.
 But the method runs fine. Does anyone know why the error message?

```
public TimedMsgBox(bool isTimed = true)
{
    *** some code here ***
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be a return problem with that error. Could you please post the full code?

Comment: Sounds like you should read the basics on how to return a Value vs when to use Void when you do not expect a return type - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Try reading this Article on when to use Void

[When and why you should use void (instead of i.e. bool/int)][1]


  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67707/when-and-why-you-should-use-void-instead-of-i-e-bool-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Visual Studio holds on to those errors even after they've already been solved for. I've had a number of times where I paused while constructing a method, got a red line underneath the next method in the class, finished my method, and still seeing that red line.

Try to Rebuild the solution (not just the plain build), or just restart Visual Studio. That typically gets rid of it for me.

EDIT: Or, if the squiggly lines in general bother you, just follow [this advice](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/disable-squiggly-or-wavy-lines-in.html) to turn them off.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a return type. Use void if none is expected.

Comment: He said it is a "method". Oh well

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error message. But again, it runs fine.

Comment: public TimedMsgBox(bool isTimed = true)

        {

            InitializeComponent();


            if (isTimed)

            {

                this.timerTimeout.Enabled = true;

                this.progressBar1.Visible = true;

            }

            else

            {

                this.timerTimeout.Enabled = false;

                this.progressBar1.Visible = false;

            }


        }

Comment: @OtávioDécio He also said `But the method runs fine`. It wouldn't compile if your answer were correct.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But running may be picking up a previously compiled binary, who knows. At least it wasn't anything really and IronMan84 solved the mistery.

Answer (score 0):

I would try taking the "=true" out of the method and defining it in the code. The IDE may be confused with the instantiation of the variable in the method...

```
    public TimedMsgBox(bool isTimed)
    {
       *** some code here   ***
    }
```

and as someone stated earlier, the method should return void if nothing is being returned

Comment: If I take out the "= true" it would no longer be an optional paraneter.

Comment: And this is a constructor. No return type is needed. Plus, return errors are different than the error that OP mentioned above.

Comment: I am still learning this site (and the language) I didn't realize that's what happened...

Comment: That's ok. You'll get used to it as you progress. Welcome to Stack Overflow!